# React Admin & Supabase: primaryKeys is undefined error

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, supabase

I am facing an issue using React Admin with ra-supabase. The following message appears in the logs and I can't find why:

`TypeError: primaryKeys is undefined`

Here are my codes:

supabase.js

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

export const supabaseClient = createClient(
  process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL,
  process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
)
```

baseDataProvider.js

```
import { supabaseDataProvider } from 'ra-supabase';
import { supabaseClient } from './supabase';

const baseDataProvider = supabaseDataProvider({
    instanceUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL,
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    supabaseClient
});

export default baseDataProvider;
```

dataProvider.js

```
import baseDataProvider from './baseDataProvider';
import {supabaseClient} from './supabase';

const dataProvider = {
  ...baseDataProvider,
  getList: async (resource, params) => {
    let result = null
    result = await baseDataProvider.getList(resource, params)
    return result
  },
}
```

App.js

```
import { Admin, CustomRoutes, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import { LoginPage, SetPasswordPage, ForgotPasswordPage } from 'ra-supabase';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Resource } from '@react-admin/ra-rbac';

import dataProvider from './Database/dataProvider';

export const App = () => {
  const classes = CustomStyles();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Admin
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
      >
        <CustomRoutes noLayout>
            <Route
                path={SetPasswordPage.path}
                element={<SetPasswordPage />}
            />
            <Route
                path={ForgotPasswordPage.path}
                element={<ForgotPasswordPage />}
            />
        </CustomRoutes>
        
        <Resource name="test" list={ListGuesser} />
      </Admin>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Finally, in supabase:

```
create table
  public.test (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    first_name text null,
    last_name text null,
    constraint test_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

I tested Supabase admin with different tables, checked connections with Supabase and tried to work around but nothing works.

Best, Marc